# How to Properly Reinstall Rotor and Stator on Suzuki DL1000

Tags: motorcycle, maintenance, installation, stator, dl1000

**Background**

I am attempting to reinstall a new Rotor and Stator onto my DL1000. I uninstalled the old parts over a year ago and haven't gotten around to the rebuild until this summer. I have some components that I do not recognize and need a bit of help identifying. I do have a PDF manual for the bike with over 500 pages so, if anyone can point me in the right direction I certainly would appreciate it.

What I've done is to put the primary gears back in place along with the rotor and stator but I have not tightened up the parts because I'm not sure of the correct placement. I also noted that the starter module that is attached to the rotor is not flush in the back and there seems to be a bigger gap than I remember when taking the rotor assembly off of the crank. (any tips on the proper re-install of this assembly?)

**Step 1**

After removing the rotor and stator, I've cleaned the plates and area. Should I be adding any lubricants to anything?

[image: step-1]

**Step 2**

Following a basic rule of thumb I just put the two primary gears back in place from where I took them. Are there any special concerns that I should perform at this point?

[image: step-2]

**Step 3**

Do I need to lube up these components before reinstalling?

[image: step-3]

**Step 4**

I noticed there is quite a gap between the rotor assembly and the back plate. From the back of the rotor, the starter component is not flush with the rotor. Should it be? Anyone able to point me to an image of the back of the rotor assembly? In fact, I seem to recall that the rotor assembly was very tightly attached to the back plate but now when reinstalling; the rotor assembly does not seem to be sticking to the back plate in the same way. I'd like to know what I am doing wrong.

[image: step-4]

**Step 5**

I do not recognize this component. I can see an [-] (i-bar) - in step 10, which I believe goes in between the space but I would really like a reference to this part if there is one in the manual or if someone has an picture of it installed.

[image: step-5]

**Step 6**

I am putting in the replacement stator. I cannot seem to find a description of the type of bolts one should use in this component. I have my old picture but I am considering using new bolts.

[image: step-6]

**Step 7**

I am trying to find information on the assembly of this component. Any pointers would be welcome.

[image: step-7]

**Step 8**

I don't recognize where the tube goes, any help would be appreciated.

[image: step-8]

**Step 9**

Another unrecognized component. If there is a part name or location in the manual please point me in the right direction.

[image: step-9]

**Step 10**

I have a number of assorted bolts and haven't been able to identify where everything goes. I haven't been able to spot these in the manual and would appreciate any pointers.

[image: step-10]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a lot of questions.  I won't be able to answer them all.  I will say I have this motor sitting in my shop and have owned a few of these,  TL/SV based.

> Should I be adding any lubricants to anything?

Yes, use assembly lube.  It's not a disaster if you don't.  Assembly lube would typically apply connecting rod and main bearings but it won't hurt you to use it when you put your clutch basket on your primary shaft.

> Following a basic rule of thumb I just put the two primary gears back in place from where I took them. Are there any special concerns that I should perform at this point?

Validate that they don't bind during operation and that they are bottomed on their respective shafts.  As well, make sure you get ALL thrust washers in their appropriate locations and order.

> Do I need to lube up these components before reinstalling?

Lube the shafts.

> I noticed there is quite a gap between the rotor assembly and the back plate. From the back of the rotor, the starter component is not flush with the rotor. Should it be? Anyone able to point me to an image of the back of the rotor assembly?

I can't tell from the picture.

> I do not recognize this component. I can see an [-] (i-bar) - in step 10, which I believe goes in between the space but I would really like a reference to this part if there is one in the manual or if someone has an picture of it installed.

Those components are related to your hydraulic clutch.  The rod goes through the primary shaft and pushes the pressure plate away from the clutch basket.  The component with three mounting bolts is the hydraulic clutch housing and piston.

> I am putting in the replacement stator. I cannot seem to find a description of the type of bolts one should use in this component. I have my old picture but I am considering using new bolts.

Get OEM bolts.  They are case hardened M4's

> I am trying to find information on the assembly of this component. Any pointers would be welcome?

That's your master cylinder again.  The line attached is for the brake fluid.  Ensure all the surfaces are clean.  The master cylinder will fit into the case. If you clean all the chain lube gunk around it you will see the mount bolt holes better, perhaps, and see how the device lines up.

> I don't recognize where the tube goes, any help would be appreciated.

That's not a tube.  It's a bushing.  It could go inside the inner clutch basket and ride on your primary shaft but the outside of it doesn't seem worn so that may be a red herring.  I don't know how much you have disassembled so it's difficult to determine where the component may have originated from.

> Another unrecognized component. If there is a part name or location in the manual please point me in the right direction.

That is an external component.  You can tell from the bolt heads.  Those are Suzuki external case cover bolts used on the outside of their engines.  The mount you have there may hold another component into place.  I would hazard a guess this piece mounts to the outside of your clutch cover.

> I have a number of assorted bolts and haven't been able to identify where everything goes. I haven't been able to spot these in the manual and would appreciate any pointers.

Impossible to say.  Need to see the state of reassembly.  I do recognize some gas tank mount bolts, internal allen head (case hardened)

I suggest you get an official Suzuki Shop manual for the DL1000.  As well, if you are having trouble finding a manual for the DL1000 you can use a manual for a 1997-2003 TL1000 or the 2003-current SV1000 manual.  The components within those engines are exactly the same as yours.  You will be quite happy you procured an official shop manual if you do.  Hope this was helpful.

Comment: This has been a great help. Thanks very much, I know it was a lot of questions and I really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem.  If you have individual issues getting it back together please feel free to throw out a bunch of related questions.  Best of luck.  Love that bike.  Lotta fun.